# Xamarin Android (C#), как обработать событие нажатия кнопки, которая находится в строке в ListView

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Нужно чтобы в момент нажатия на строку (ListView Item) обрабатывалась одно событие, а при клике на кнопки (+ Или -) другие.

[image: скриншот]

1. Activty OnCreate

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeActivity);

       this.SearchView = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView);
       this.SearchView.QueryTextChange += SearchView_QueryTextChange;
       this.Adapter = new ProductsLiostViewAdapter(this, ProductAPIConection.GetProducts(), Resource.Layout.ProductListViewRow);
       this.ProductsListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ProductListView);
       this.ProductsListView.Adapter = this.Adapter;
       this.ProductsListView.ItemClick += ProductsListView_ItemClick;
       this.GoToCartPage = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.GoToCartPage);
       this.GoToCartPage.Click += GoToCartPage_Click;
   }

   private void GoToCartPage_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CartActivity));
       StartActivity(intent); 
   }
   ```
2. LitView Adapter GetView

   ```
   public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
       var row = convertView;

       if (row == null)
       {
           row = LayoutInflater.From(this.Context).Inflate(this.Layout, null, false);
       }
       var ImageView = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ProductImageView);
       ImageView.SetImageBitmap(this.Products[position].Image);
       var NameTextView = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ProductNameTextView);
       NameTextView.Text = this.Products[position].Name;
       var PriceTextView = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ProductPriceTextView);
       PriceTextView.Text = $"{this.Products[position].Price.ToString()} $";
       var BrandTextView = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ProductBrandTextView);
       BrandTextView.Text = this.Products[position].Brand;


       if (convertView == null)
       {
           var CountTextView = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CountTextView);
           var PlusImageView = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.PlusImageView);
           var MinusImageView = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.MinusImageView);
           PlusImageView.Click += delegate
           {
               Console.WriteLine("==============================");

               var pos = position;
               if (this.Products[pos].Quantity > this.ProductCount[pos])
               {
                   this.ProductCount[pos]++;
               }
               else
               {
                   Toast.MakeText(this.Context, "The maximum number.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
               }
               var TempCountTextView = CountTextView;
               TempCountTextView.Text = this.ProductCount[pos].ToString();
           };

           MinusImageView.Click += delegate
           {
               var pos = position;
               if (this.ProductCount[pos] > 0)
               {
                   this.ProductCount[pos]--;
               }
               var TempCountTextView = CountTextView;
               TempCountTextView.Text = this.ProductCount[position].ToString();
           };
       }
       return row;
   }
   ```
3. ListView item axml

Comment: сложно рассказывать человеку что-либо без ориентирования в его понятиях, если вы выложите сюда код, в соответствии с правилами, вам быстрее подскажут. Пока я вижу только картинку могу сказать что вам надо на событие ListView Item onChange - подвесить событие, взять кнопки, перевести их на передний фронт, и подписать на событие  onclick.

Comment: вот пример кода, если не я я весь проект показать

Comment: сократите код в соответствии с правилами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Из всего кода лучше оставить только создание строки, при этом в создании строки оставить только создание кнопок "+" и "-", а так же контрола для количества.

Comment: В этом случае кнопки "+" и "-" работают, но не вызывается событие ListView.ItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

Так как инициализация полей происходит с модели которая лежит в коллекции, то модель нужно расширить( создать дочернюю)
Эта вьюмодель будет содержать в себе ссылку на родительскую вьюмодель и два комманда которые будут обращаться к методам на родителе, передаем в этот метод те данные которые нам нужны( будь то текущий айтем или еще что) и делаем то что нам нужно.
Забайндить клик по кнопкам в айтемтемплейте можно так же как и клик по простой комманде.